# Show the child and grandchild page content in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, grandchild

I have a page structure like this in Wordpress:

- Main Page

  - Main page child

    - Main page grandchild
    - Main page grandchild
    - Main page grandchild
    - Main page grandchild
  - Main page child

    - Main page grandchild
    - Main page grandchild
    - Main page grandchild
    - Main page grandchild

etc...

I just want to show the title/content for each child page/grandchild page on the main page it's self, please can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `wp_list_pages()` function, and specify a *top ancestor* and level of `2`.

```
<?php 

  $postid = get_the_ID();
  $topid = get_top_ancestor($postid); 

  $args = array(
          'depth'        => 2,
          'show_date'    => '',
          'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
          'child_of'     => $topid,
          'exclude'      => '',
          'include'      => '',
          'title_li'     => '',
          'echo'         => 1,
          'authors'      => '',
          'sort_order'   => 'ASC',
          'link_before'  => '',
          'link_after'   => '',
          'walker'       => '',
          'post_type'    => 'page',
          'post_status'  => 'publish' 
  ); ?>
<ul>
  <?php wp_list_pages( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for that...but I want to show the content and title for each of these child pages and grandchild pages, rather than listing the pages. Any ideas please?